# my navbar got a problem when scroll (text be transculent in my navbar)

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

[when I scroll my navbar text which should not be translucent in my navbar how can I solve this problem? for more details, see the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra2f9.jpg)

Comment: where is your code? edit your question and add it

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm guessing the `z-index` property in the css class of the Nav bar could help you.

```
.navbar
{
z-index: 100;
}
```

z-index is like a layer number, with the largest number always showing on top.

This should keep your navbar on top of text and images on your page.

Comment: Hi Daniel; welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't answer off-topic questions like this! For future reference, questions asking why code isn't working **must** include a [mcve] in the question itself. Answering such questions that lack required information sends the message to viewers that the rules don't matter.